# How would you express colons in speaking?

Tags: pronunciation, punctuation

There are two colons in the following lines a radio personality is speaking. How does the speaker get his listeners to feel the existence of colons? Maybe intonation? or a shorter pause?

(On the radio)

> ”Listeners, that brings us to the end of another *Potterwatch.* We don’t know when it will be possible to broadcast again, but you can be sure we shall be back. Keep twiddling those dials: The next password will be ‘Mad-Eye.’ Keep each other safe: Keep faith. Good night.” (*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (7)* [US Version p.444])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, I'd use both raised pitch (like the comma in a somewhat emphatic reading of "If you want to go, I won't stop you") and a pause (like after a sentence). But that may be just me.